# Format N_STRING parameter from TCP data

Tags: php, tcp, gps, format

I have a GPS device sending packets to my server (Linux with PHP listener) via TCP, i have all the parameters but one, I/O State.

The tk207 Protocol defines that parameter as this:

```
IO State
Length: 8 bits
Type: N_STRING 
1:Main power, '0' means on power, '1'  means off power。
2:ACC, '0' ACC close, '1' ACC open
3:   blender, '0'  Did not.start, '1' Just turning, '2' reverse turning。
4:Empty/heavy vehicles, '0' Did not.start, '1' Empty, '2' Heavy
5:Front door, '0' Did not start, ’1’ open, '2' close。
6: off the oil state, '1' '0' recovery oil
7: arm / disarm state, '1' '0' from the 8 fortification: there is no vibration
```

**N_STRING definition:** Contain the digit character string of 0.9. When fix digits, fill in ASCII code 0(Ox30H) on left for lacking digit except for special instruction.

I am getting values like this EDITED*

```
01000000
01000001
11000000
11000001
```

But i am unable to figure out how to get the 7 parameters from that string.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
Before i had the definition about the field, i was looking at some examples on how to retreive the on/off value from this field

```
$gpioInput = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    $b = substr($gpioStr, 7 - $i, 1);
    if ($b != "0") {
        $gpioInput |= (1 << $i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Before i found that definition i was trying to get the on/off parameter like this $gpioInput = 0;
                for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
                    $b = substr($gpioStr, 7 - $i, 1);
                    if ($b != "0") {
                        $gpioInput |= (1 << $i);
                    }
                }

Comment: Please edit your original post to add code and/or new information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding you tried to get access to a "global" value, which is an aggregation of all the fields `$gpioInput |= (1 << $i);` If it's so and it's "Off" when any digit is zero, then next code should be helpful.

```
<?php

const TK207_MAIN_POWER_ON = 0;
const TK207_MAIN_POWER_OFF = 1;

const TK207_ACC_CLOSE = 0;
const TK207_ACC_OPEN = 1;

const TK207_BLENDER_DID_NOT_START = 0;
const TK207_BLENDER_JUST_TURNING = 1;
const TK207_BLENDER_REVERSE_TURNING = 2;

const TK207_VEHICLES_DID_NOT_START = 0;
const TK207_VEHICLES_EMPTY = 1;
const TK207_VEHICLES_HEAVY = 2;

const TK207_FRONT_DOOR_DID_NOT_START = 0;
const TK207_FRONT_DOOR_OPEN = 1;
const TK207_FRONT_DOOR = 2;

const TK207_OFF_THE_OIL_OFF = 0;
const TK207_OFF_THE_OIL_RECOVERY = 1;

const TK207_STATE_ARM = 0; // ???
const TK207_STATE_DISARM = 1; // ???

//-------------------------------

function isOn($str) {
    return (int)array_reduce(str_split($str), function($carry, $item) {
            $carry &= (bool)$item;
            return $carry;
    }, 1);
}

function getValues($str) {
    return str_split($str);
}

function getOnOffValues($str) {
    return array_map(function ($item) {
        return (int)(bool)$item;
    }, str_split($str));
}

//-------------------------------

$offStr = '11210211';
$onStr  = '11211211';

echo isOn($offStr); // off

echo isOn($onStr); // on

list($mainPower, $acc, $blender, $vehicles, $frontDoor, $oil, $armDisarm) = getValues($onStr);
var_dump([$mainPower, $acc, $blender, $vehicles, $frontDoor, $oil, $armDisarm]);

list($mainPower, $acc, $blender, $vehicles, $frontDoor, $oil, $armDisarm) = getOnOffValues($offStr);
var_dump([$mainPower, $acc, $blender, $vehicles, $frontDoor, $oil, $armDisarm]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something fundamental here, but from what I can understand from the definition it seems to be quite simple: Each IO-state value is a string of 8 bits, returned as a string value instead of a normal byte.

Taking the first line of the example you provided, and turning it 90 degrees for readability:

```
 0 <- Fill digit.
 1 <- Main power: Off.
 0 <- ACC: Closed
 0 <- Blender: Did not start
 0 <- Empty/Heavy: Did not start.
 0 <- Front door: Did not start.
 0 <- Oil state
 0 <- Arm/disarm
```

Then just do the same for the three other lines.

A quick way to make it into an array, is by using `str_split()`. Which might make it a bit easier to traverse, or manipulate if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's a string type , not a binary type returned by service. 
So you can handle it like :

```
foreach(str_split($gpioStr,8) as $gpioStrLine){
  // $gpioStrLine[0]<- Fill digit.
  // $gpioStrLine[1]<- Main power.
  // $gpioStrLine[2]<- ACC
  // $gpioStrLine[3]<- Blender
  // $gpioStrLine[4]<- Empty/Heavy.
  // $gpioStrLine[5]<- Front door.
  // $gpioStrLine[6]<- Oil state
  // $gpioStrLine[7]<- Arm/disarm
}
```